# Displaying Visio diagram on page very very slow

Tags: visio

I have several Visio Diagrams that I wish to display on individual SharePoint pages.  They are very simple diagrams (less than 50kb in some cases)  They contain nothing clever only links to documents stored on SharePoint.

I have added them using the Visio app but for some reason when you open the page it takes upwards of 40 seconds for the image to appear.

This is a major blocker to my project so need urgent help

Thanks

Comment: Check this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-visio/visio-2013-very-slow/8b902353-6fb7-49e7-9cee-36ee9fc0c471?page=2&auth=1